# Excel changes non variable conditional formatting formula

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm busy making a method which checks if a column is filled with less than X percent. If that happens, I want them to highlight the row. Now on my PC it works and I'm running Windows 7. But on the pc of my companion it acts weird, on 1 pc it doesn't work at all. And on the other pc it changes the formula "=COUNTA($XX2)>0" To "=COUNTA($XX3)>0" (XX are the column names, for example: AS, BC)

It's a string with only the column variable, how can it change in excel?

So far i tried running the programma on 5 pc's, It works on 3 pc's, but not the 2 of my companion, who actually needs the program.

Here's my code:

```
    public void HightlightErrors(int percent)
    {
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        string strRange = "2:" + last.Row; //Range concludes to $2:$<nr>
        Range myRange = worksheet.get_Range(strRange);
        int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
        int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
        for (int i = 1; i < lastUsedColumn; i++) //Check each column to see if it is less than 5% filled.
        {
            Range currentColumn = worksheet.Columns[i];
            if(currentColumn.Value2[1,1].Contains("NOTITIE")) //When a note is made, it's never a wrong file.
            {
                continue;
            }
            double a = application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(currentColumn);
            if (((a / lastUsedRow) * 100) < percent)
            {
                string columnChar = GetExcelColumnName(i);
                string redCondition = "=COUNTA($"+ columnChar + "2)>0";

                dynamic format = myRange.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1: redCondition);
                format.Interior.Color = 0x0000FF;
            } 
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(last);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myRange);
    }
```

Comment: The 3 pc's i tested on, and which worked are:
- Windows XP + Excel 2010
- Windows 7 + Excel 2010
- Windows 7 + Excel 2010 (I programmed on this one)

The pc's which didn't work perfectly is a Windows XP + Excel 2010 and a Windows 7 + Excel 2010.

I fixed 1, because he had a dutch version installed, and COUNTA doesn't exist in dutch, i had to be AANTALARG. So i got that one, but I still haven't found the answer to the pc which turns the 2 into a 3. (From the Counta "2)>0")

Comment: I tried it in a new sheet and had the same problem. Still turning the 2 into a 3... I can't find the problem, when debugging I can see it insert a 2.